# Gallery not working on iPad/Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For some reason my gallery isn't working on Mobile devices including iPad, works fine on desktop. Instead of allowing a user to click through, all images appear stacked. The [link](http://www.gatehouse75.com/gallery/) to my site.  The code is
located [here](http://www.gatehouse75.com/wp-content/themes/gatehouse/js/jquery.main.js)

```
// scroll gallery init
function initCarousel() {
var isTouchDevice = /MSIE 10.*Touch/.test(navigator.userAgent) || ('ontouchstart' in    window) || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch;
jQuery('div.view-gallery').scrollGallery({
    mask: 'div.frame',
    slider: '>ul',
    slides: '>li',
    btnPrev: 'a.btn-prev',
    btnNext: 'a.btn-next',
    pagerLinks: '.pagination li',
    circularRotation: false,
    autoRotation: false,
    switchTime: 3000,
    animSpeed: 500,
    onInit: function(obj){
        obj.resizeFlag = true;
        obj.win = jQuery(window);
        //obj.win.unbind('resize orientationchange load', obj.onWindowResize);
        obj.resizeSlides = function(){
            obj.slideOffset = obj.slides.eq(0).outerWidth(true) -   obj.slides.eq(0).width();
            if(!obj.resizeFlag) obj.slides.css({width: ''});
            else obj.slides.css({width: obj.mask.width()/2 - obj.slideOffset});
            obj.calculateOffsets();
            obj.refreshPosition();
            obj.refreshState();
        }
        if(isTouchDevice){
            ResponsiveHelper.addRange({
                '..767': {
                    on: function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            obj.resizeFlag = true;
                            obj.resizeSlides();
                            obj.win.bind('resize  orientationchange load', obj.resizeSlides);
                        }, 100);
                    }
                },
                '768..': {
                    on: function(){
                        obj.resizeFlag = false;
                        obj.win.unbind('resize orientationchange  load', obj.resizeSlides);
                        obj.resizeSlides();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
jQuery('.scrollable-gallery').scrollableGallery();
}

/*
 * scrollableGallery
 */
 ;(function($) {
function ScrollableGallery(options) {
    this.options = {
        scrollableArea: '.frame',
        listItems: '.list-items',
        btnPrev: '.btn-prev',
        btnNext: '.btn-next',
        animSpeed: 500
    }
    $.extend(this.options, options);
    this.init();
}
ScrollableGallery.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        this.findElements()
        this.setStructure();
        this.addEvents();
    },
    findElements: function() {
        this.holder = $(this.options.holder);
        this.scrollableArea = this.holder.find(this.options.scrollableArea);
        this.listItems = this.scrollableArea.find(this.options.listItems);
        this.items = this.listItems.children();
        this.lastItem = this.items.last();
        this.btnPrev = this.holder.find(this.options.btnPrev);
        this.btnNext = this.holder.find(this.options.btnNext);

        this.scrollAPI = new jcf.modules.customscroll({
            replaces: this.scrollableArea[0]
        });
    },
    setStructure: function() {
        var that = this;

        if (that.listItems.css('position') === 'static') {
            that.listItems.css('position', 'relative');
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            that.refreshState();
        }, 50);
    },
    refreshState: function() {
        this.listItems.css('width', 32700);
        this.listItems.css('width', this.lastItem.position().left +   this.lastItem.outerWidth(true) + 1);
        this.scrollableArea.add(this.scrollableArea.parent()).css({
            width: '',
            height: ''
        });
        this.scrollAPI.refreshState();
    },
    addEvents: function() {
        var that = this;

        that.btnPrev.bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            that.prevSlide();
        });
        that.btnNext.bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            that.nextSlide();
        });

        win.bind('resize orientationchange load', function() {
            that.refreshState();
        });
    },
    nextSlide: function() {
        var that = this;
        var curPos = this.scrollableArea.scrollLeft();
        var pos;

        for (var i = 0; i < that.items.length; i++) {
            pos = that.items.eq(i).position().left;
            if (pos > curPos) {
                that.scrollAnimate(curPos, pos);
                break;
            }
        }
    },
    prevSlide: function() {
        var that = this;
        var curPos = this.scrollableArea.scrollLeft();
        var pos;

        for (var i = that.items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            pos = that.items.eq(i).position().left;
            if (pos < curPos) {
                that.scrollAnimate(curPos, pos);
                break;
            }
        }
    },
    scrollAnimate: function(from, to) {
        var that = this;
        var start = new Date().getTime();

        setTimeout(function() {
            var now = (new Date().getTime()) - start;
            var progress = now / that.options.animSpeed;
            var result = (to - from) * progress + from;
            that.scrollAPI.hScrollBar.scrollTo(result);
            if (progress < 1) {
                setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10);
            } else {
                that.scrollAPI.hScrollBar.scrollTo(to);
            }
        }, 10);
    }
}

var win = $(window);

$.fn.scrollableGallery = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (!$(this).data('ScrollableGallery')) {
            $(this).data('ScrollableGallery', new   ScrollableGallery($.extend({}, {holder: this}, options)));
        }
    });
}
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: What platform are you testing the mobile part on?

Comment: iPad, Android, Iphone, Windows Phone 8. Doesn't work on any of them.

Comment: r you using Jquery mobile ?

Comment: No, but I have my own mobile style sheet.

Comment: You appear to have a stray semicolon at line 55... Also, dont use the /* for commenting in JS. Use //.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through your code, there were numerous errors with syntax. I have cleaned them up as best as I could, this should help you out.

http://jsfiddle.net/wvWrY/1/

For example, this area was missing a semicolon (no way to call the findElements function, as JS will simply skip to the next line without a semicolon there.)

```
init: function() {
    this.findElements()
    this.setStructure();
    this.addEvents();
```

Run your code through a linter, it will greatly improve your syntax structure and ensure little leave out errors like semicolons and commas and brackets aren't omitted.

EDIT: Ok, having looked at your code it appears this is actually due to the !importants in your allmobile.css file. The width and height are set to max-width: 100% (this breaks it because the way the slider works is to extend the gallery as far off screen as possible) and the height to auto (this breaks it because it allows the images to just keep piling on). Once you remove those for the page, it become much much much better and actually works.

Comment: Thanks. Cleaned up. Still the same issue.

Comment: @RyanTravis Hmm took a look at your link and it still appears to be the old code. Would you mind updating it so I can take a look at it in real time and see how its interacting...

Comment: @RyanTravis Looks like I found a fix. I have updated my answer to reflect this.